# Dagger2 Found Dependency Cycle Android

Tags: android, dagger-2

Im learning and newer to Dagger2 and stuck in the issue where I need to use both @Provides and @Binds in a Module. but its giving error

```
[Dagger/DependencyCycle] Found a dependency cycle:
 public interface CarComponent{
        ^
      com.stupido.daggertutorial.Engine is injected at
          com.stupido.daggertutorial.CarModule.bindsEngine(arg0)
      com.stupido.daggertutorial.Engine is injected at
          com.stupido.daggertutorial.CarModule.providesCar(engine, …)
      com.stupido.daggertutorial.Car is requested at
          com.stupido.daggertutorial.CarComponent.getCar()
```

before I was using @Provides it worked fine but with combination I get above issue.

**Component**

```
@Component(modules = CarModule.class)
 public interface CarComponent{
    //constructor injection
    Car getCar();
    
}
```

**Module**

```
@Module
public abstract class CarModule {
    @Binds
    abstract Wheels bindsWheels(Wheels wheels);

    @Binds
    abstract Engine bindsEngine(Engine engine);

    @Provides
     static Car providesCar(Engine engine,Wheels wheels){
        return new Car(wheels,engine);
    }
}
```

**Activity**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        CarComponent carComponent = DaggerCarComponent.create();
        Car car = carComponent.getCar();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`@Binds` is usually for the case when you have some inherited class and its interface and you want dagger to know this and be able to inject the interface. Usually you'd have

```
@Binds
abstract Engine bindsEngine(DieselEngine dieselEngine);
```

and then you can just inject engine without knowing the implementation detail (it's diesel engine).

In your case, if you remove both `@Binds` methods, it should start working (if there's no other issue).

Answer (score 1):

You are using `@Binds` in the wrong way. Please read their documentation.

*A @Binds method:

Must have a single parameter whose type is assignable to the return type. The return type declares the bound type (just as it would for a @Provides method) and the parameter is the type to which it is bound.*

You have to change @Binds to @Provides.

Comment: but where ever I am using @Binds there is a single parameter whose type is also the return type of that method. e.g. in my case bindsWheels and bindsEngine

Comment: This is not the right case for using @Binds in your case